# Can you use a ring of telekinesis to bend bars, break down a door or lift a portcullis?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, objects

As per the ring description, you can only target objects that aren't being worn or carried up to 1,000 lbs. So can you use it to do things like wrenching open a closed door or lifting a heavy portcullis (possibly with an ability check using your spellcasting ability modifier)?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, it seems to be asking the same question about moving large objects that may be attached to other objects.